# Need to add views inside a slide bar in my application

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android development and I want to add views inside a Slide bar. It must hide and view the elements by overlapping the layout.

As I have attached a screenshot of calculator app which has the same. I want to implement the same layout. What layout should I use to achieve this design?

[image: Slide Bar view in Calculator app]